# Screen extend to the left and primary screen selection on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

Hope I am in the right Stack Exchange website. I have successfully extended my laptop screen to an external monitor which is placed in the left of my laptop. I have set the display settings accordingly, so the computer recognizes that the external monitor is on my left.

[image: Screen Shot]

Although, my desktop items appear on the left screen (the external monitor) by default. Is there any way I can change that? I want my desktop items to appear on the laptop screen which is the primary and use the external monitor for supplementary actions.

Answer (score 2):

I run a two monitor setup as well and in theory, you should just need to select your right monitor and check the "Make this my main display" box below the area you screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to drag your screen icon to change left or right. Below is the screenshot of windows 8.
[image]